# Should I be using multiple p elements or a single p element with br elements in it when marking up novels?

Tags: html

I'm wanting to know if what I'm doing is the "right way" even though in programming(thought HTML isn't really a programming language) there are several ways to solve a problem.

I'm currently applying my current knowledge of HTML by making a website that users can read novels/books in it. I wanna know if I should use multiple p elements for every paragraph or a single paragraph with multiple br elements.

I'm currently using multiple p elements. So I'm having doubts if this is a correct way. Sometimes there are paragraphs in the book that only takes up on line, usually when a conversation is happening with the characters, so there's a lot of p elements in my html file.

```
<p>
    Look, I didn't want to be a half-blood.    
</p>
<p>
    If you're reading this because you think you might be one, my advice 
is: close this book right now. Believe whatever lie your mom or dad told you about your birth, and try to lead a normal life.
</p>
<p>
    Being a half-blood is dangerous. It's scary. Most of the time, it gets you killed in paiful, nasty ways.
</p>
<p>
    If you're a normal kid, reading this because you think it's fiction, great. Read on. I envy you for being able to believe that none of this ever happened.
</p>
<p>
    But if you recognize yourself in thses pages&mdash;if you feel something stirring inside&mdash;stop reading immediately. You might be one of us. And once you know that, it's only a matter of time before <em>they</em> sense it too, and they'll come for you.
</p>
<p>
    Don't say I didn't warn you.
</p>
<hr>
<p>
    My name is Percy Jackson.
</p>
<p>
    I'm twelve years old. Until a few months ago, I was a boarding student at Yancy Academy, a private school for troubled kids in upstate New York.
</p>
<p>
    Am I a troubled kid?
</p>
<p>
    Yeah. You could say that.
</p>
<p>
    I could start at any point in my short miserable life to prove it, but things really started going bad last May, when our sixth-grade class took a field trip to Manhattan&mdash;twenty-eight mental-case kids and two teachers on a yellow school bus, heading to the Metropolitan Museum of Art to look at ancient Greek and Roman stuff.
</p>
<p>
    I know&mdash;it sounds like torture. Most Yancy field trips were.
</p>
<p>
    But Mr. Brunner, our Latin teacher, was leading this trip, so I had hopes
</p>
```

So the result looks the same as how it looks like in the book. But the only thing I'm wondering is if it would be better to just use a single p element and then use different br elements.

Comment: I'd stick with your solution rather than using "br" it's cleaner and easier for you to read! I'd then use css classes to differentiate between different type paragraphs (dialogues, quotes...)

Answer (score 1):

The `<p>` tag is for paragraphs, so if they really are paragraphs (not always easy to say), they should all be wrapped with their own `<p>` tag. I like to think about the `<br>` more like a shift+enter, if you know what I mean... If you want my advice, stick with your current method, and use `<br>` only if it is really obvious.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends upon the look and feel that you would like to give to your users.   Although I would suggest to carry-on with the same approach. It will be easier for you to manage you code and editing content.